PostGIS Clustering Issue
I am attempting to write a function which will use PostGIS to group geometric points based off the bounding box passed to the function.
I created the following table:

CREATE TABLE items (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    location GEOMETRY(Point, 4326)  -- SRID 4326 for geographic coordinates
);

And populated it with random data within a specified bounding box using the following code:
DO
$$
DECLARE
    i INT := 0;
    min_lat FLOAT := 54.542;
    max_lat FLOAT := 54.559;
    min_lon FLOAT := -5.761;
    max_lon FLOAT := -5.729;
    rand_lat FLOAT;
    rand_lon FLOAT;
BEGIN
    WHILE i < 1000 LOOP
        -- Generate random latitude and longitude within the bounding box
        rand_lat := min_lat + (max_lat - min_lat) * random();
        rand_lon := min_lon + (max_lon - min_lon) * random();
        
        -- Insert a new row with the generated location
        INSERT INTO items (location)
        VALUES (ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(rand_lon, rand_lat), 4326));

        i := i + 1;
    END LOOP;
END
$$;

The function to perform the clustering looks like this:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_items_within_bbox(
    min_x FLOAT, 
    min_y FLOAT, 
    max_x FLOAT, 
    max_y FLOAT, 
    cluster_distance FLOAT
)
RETURNS TABLE (
    item_id INT, 
    cluster_id BIGINT, 
    cluster_geom GEOMETRY, 
    cluster_count BIGINT
) AS $$
DECLARE
    bbox GEOMETRY;
BEGIN
    -- Create the bounding box geometry
    bbox := ST_MakeEnvelope(min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y, 4326);

    RETURN QUERY
    WITH items_in_bbox AS (
        SELECT 
            i.id AS item_id, 
            i.location AS item_location
        FROM items i
        WHERE ST_Intersects(i.location, bbox) 
    ),
    clusters AS (
        SELECT 
            unnest(ST_ClusterWithin(item_location, cluster_distance)) AS cluster_geom
        FROM items_in_bbox
    ),
    cluster_points AS (
        SELECT 
            i.item_id AS point_id,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS point_cluster_id, 
            c.cluster_geom AS cluster_geom
        FROM items_in_bbox i
        JOIN clusters c ON ST_Intersects(i.item_location, c.cluster_geom) 
    ),
    cluster_counts AS (
        SELECT 
            cp.point_cluster_id AS cluster_id, 
            COUNT(*) AS cluster_count 
        FROM cluster_points cp
        GROUP BY cp.point_cluster_id
    )
    SELECT 
        MIN(cp.point_id) AS item_id,  
        cp.point_cluster_id AS cluster_id, 
        ST_Collect(cp.cluster_geom) AS cluster_geom,  
        cc.cluster_count AS cluster_count
    FROM cluster_points cp
    JOIN cluster_counts cc ON cp.point_cluster_id = cc.cluster_id 
    GROUP BY cp.point_cluster_id, cc.cluster_count; 
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

I then attempt to call the function using:
SELECT * FROM get_items_within_bbox(
    -5.761,  -- min_x (West Longitude)
    54.542,  -- min_y (South Latitude)
    -5.729,  -- max_x (East Longitude)
    54.559,  -- max_y (North Latitude)
    1609.34  -- cluster_distance in meters
);

No matter what value I supply for the cluster_distance, I always get 1000 rows of data returned and the cluster_count of each item is always 1.

The unit of measurement of EPSG:4326 is degree, not meter, and 1609.34 degrees is a rather unearthly range... While you could apply a cosinuidal factor to get an approximate degree value for an average latitude of your AOI, your best bet is to find a suitable projection and ST_Transform your geometries accordingly.
